# Why RAMDisk file copying of lots of small files slower than on SSD?

Tags: ssd, file-transfer, speed, copy-paste, ramdisk

I'm very confused with results of copying folder with around 10 000 small files (250 MB total size):

Copying from **SSD** to the same SSD (850 Evo 500GB) took **35 seconds**.
Also for info CrystalDiskMark shows RND4K Q1T1 30 MB/s read and 70 MB/s write for this drive.

But copying from **RAMDisk** to the same RAMDisk (created by OSFMount, formatted as NTFS) took **2 minutes!**
Also for info CrystalDiskMark shows RND4K Q1T1 700 MB/s read and 600 MB/s write for this drive.

There is no CPU bottleneck, as load for any of 4 CPU cores was like 50 % or even less.

It's intuitive to assume that RAMDisk is way faster than SSD and should do file operations lightning fast, which is indeed the case for large files, but appears totally wrong for large amounts of small files.

**Can anyone clarify why this happens?**

Comment: Overheads, and poorly written ramdrive software? The CPU will have to do a lot of block level filesystem management and read/writes that would normally simply pass through a cache on the way to the drive. Possibly several times more memory accesses happening in the ram disk when seeking and/or writing files. How much memory does your computer have? How large a ram disk? How much data in these files? How many files? What is the average file size?

Comment: I'm already specified that folder is around 10 000 small files (250 MB total size). Actually it's gradle-6.5.1 folder. 16GB of memory, always have at least few GB free, I tried size of RAMDisk 600MB, 3GB and 5GB with no difference.
How is CPU concerned as CPU load far from maximum on any core? Does Windows 10 somehow restricts maximum CPU load for copying files?

Comment: “It's intuitive to assume that RAMDisk is way faster than SSD” - Why do you believe this is true?  Honestly, the CrystalDiskMark performance benchmarks doesn’t seem real.  Are you able to confirm those benchmarks with another tool?

Comment: Hmm, because it's RAM, it's supposed to be very fast. Of course I can check with another tool, but which one?

Comment: What type of RAM? How many sticks? Is it operating in dual or single channel? RAM may well be fast but you have seeks to find the partition, the MFT within it, walk the tree in the MFT to get the file location, start reading at that location and so on rather than simply doing block requests to some black box. All those seeks require going back and forth to memory several times and are effectively overheads of small files. RAM might be fast but having to do 4 bits of back and forth just to get one small bit of data will effectively quarter your bandwidth.

Comment: Then that received data may get copied into the Windows disk cache, meaning more memory accesses further decreasing the bandwidth available to the RAM drive. Explorer (or whatever program you are using) will also be using bandwidth to scan the file list it got back further limiting the RAM disk. RAM is fast, but you are sharing it with everything else that is working on the data rather than having the data in another device that just hands you a bunch of blocks as you ask for them. NTFS is designed for block based devices and may not be efficient in this case.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, sounds like something like that could have happened. Actually my PC running pretty old DDR2-1333, dual channel 2x8GB. Is there some way to check RAM activity to know that it's under maximum load and really just can't handle this overheads? Can RAMDisk on faster memory dramatically change results? Does result depend on software that created RAMDisk?

Comment: Well [DDR3-1333](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) can do 10GB/s per channel, so 20GB/s, and DDR4-3200 could do 25GB/s per channel for ~50GB/s total. So conceivably a newer system might be twice as fast. Depending on whether you have integrated graphics there may also be another drop in speed there as the integrated may also be using some bandwidth.

Comment: I have discrete video card. I don't know, still seems strange if it's related to bandwidth, because 20GB/s for 2 minutes is 2 400 000 MB, and folder size is roughly 240 MB, so 1000 times difference! Even considering possible overheads and sharing bandwidth with other applications it still seems too much.
I think I will test another RAMDisk software, and also hope next week will be able to test on new PC with DDD4-3600.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer to answer this mystic. I have tested copying on new PC and get 80 seconds for both RAMDisk (DDD4-3600) and SSD (NVME GEN4, not SATA SSD from old PC). 120 and 80 seconds is a good correlation between single threaded performance of old and new CPUs.
Finally I tried to disable Real-time protection in Windows 10. Got 10 seconds for RAMDisk and 14 seconds for NVME SSD. On my old machine gradle folder was added to antivirus exceptions, so that's why it was faster than RAM. Will test later if 35 second is real performance of old system. Anyway now it finally makes sense!